# enabling auto scanning using resteasy 3.0.10 with wildfly 8.2

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly-8

I am trying to figure out what is my problem while setting up new Wildfly 8.2 server with simple restEasy 3.0.10 application.

my web application is supre easy.

```
src/main/
   java/my-package/
      RootApplication.java
      HomePageResource.java
   webapp/
      index.html
      WEB-INF/
         beans.xml
         web.xml
```

web.xml and beans.xml look like this

```
---- web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">
</web-app>
---- beans.xml
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

in RootApplication.java I have

```
@ApplicationPath("/app")
public class RootApplication extends Application
{
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public RootApplication()
    {
        singletons.add(new HomePageResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        return singletons;
    }
}

// ResourceProvider is a simple class hiding getResource and createStreamer
@Path("/")
public class HomePageResource extends ResourceProvider
{
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomePageResource.class);

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getHomePage()
    {
        final InputStream homePageResource = getResource("/static/view/home/home.html");
        return Response.ok(createStreamer(homePageResource)).build();
    }
}
```

which works but I have never specified any resource classes inside Application and RestEasy was always able to scan WAR content. And if I remove everything from RootApplication, like this.

```
@ApplicationPath("/app")
public class RootApplication extends Application
{
}
```

Anyway documentation also says (https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/)

> Since we're not using a jax-rs servlet mapping, we must define an Application class that is annotated with the @ApplicationPath annotation. **If you return any empty set for by classes and singletons, your WAR will be scanned for JAX-RS annotation resource and provider classes.**

any hints what I may do wrong with this simple setup??? and another question can I remove beans.xml to use guice DI, I understand this problem has nothing to do with CDI/WELD.

my pom.xml looks like this

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can You show `HomePageResource.java` too?

Comment: sure, I ll add it to main question

Answer (score 4):

There is a good [tutorial by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/) which provides you examples on how to configure your web service application with *or* without `resteasy.scan`.

Based on your question your `web.xml` is empty? That would mean `resteasy.scan` is set to `false` as per [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#d4e125):

> resteasy.scan - Default value: false - Automatically scan WEB-INF/lib jars and WEB-INF/classes directory for both @Provider and JAX-RS resource classes (@Path, @GET, @POST etc..) and register them

I usually set `resteasy.scan` to false and register my resources manually, because sometimes my `WEB-INF/lib` jars were containing providers/resources and they broke my application. Here is the configuration I am using:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>My application name</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.bar.Configuration</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Configuration.java**

```
package com.foo.bar;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class Configuration extends Application {

    public Configuration() {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(EntryPoint.class);
        return classes;
    }

}
```